# Show page number on printing in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would want show the page number at the bottom of my printable document. I found a source and follow an [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654071/print-page-count-with-total-number-of-pages-using-css) here but it does not help.

My current CSS to achieve this desire is like this:

```
body {
  text-align: justify;
}

/* class to break into new page */
.pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }

@media print {
    body {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
@bottom-right {
    content: "ទំព័រទី " counter(page) " នៃ " counter(pages);
}
```

However, when I test print document, it does not show my page number at all.

What was wrong to my css? How can I do to achieve this result?

Thanks.

**Edited**

After I spent sometimes searched through this, I know of most major browser not support this `@bottom-right`. Any thought of it?

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654071/print-page-count-with-total-number-of-pages-using-css mentioned in the link comment, you should try different browser.

Comment: @user3888958, thanks. I tried in FF, chrome, and Safari, but still not showing page number.

Comment: In what context do you print the HTML? If you are the only one printing it, you could look at a program like [Prince](https://www.princexml.com/); according to [Smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/#putting-it-all-together-an-example-book) it is one of few user agents which supports it.

I unfortunatly cannot help you if it is for a 'commercial' site where others might want to print it. This due to having no experience with it myself.

Comment: @Yemachu, thanks very much for suggestion. I'm doing for my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of 12/3/2015, the margin boxes like @bottom-center don't appear to
>   be supported by the major browsers, as shown here. If you search for
>   "@bottom-center" you'll see a whole lot of red "not supported" boxes.
>   When you search the web it sounds like they should work but in reality
>   they're not supported yet. Some elements of paged media work great,
>   like page-break-after, but not the margin boxes. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074133/2397550)

However, there seems to be [a solutions that works in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20317775/2397550).

Comment: Thanks. Printing between Firefox and Chrome as they look bit different during printing. Therefore I recommend my user to use chrome instead of Firefox as Chrome look better than Firefox.

Comment: Chrome is a terrible browser from a privacy point-of-view. If you care about your client(s company secrets), you advice him/her to move to Firefox anyway.