# css: numbering printed pages in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, google-chrome

The browser that I have to support is Chrome (using electron for my project), so using any other browser is not an option.

I've looked for the solution to this problem for a while, it doesn't seem to have an answer to it. I've tried using this form of approach (copied from [CSS page x of y for @media print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711147/css-page-x-of-y-for-media-print)):

The CSS is:

```
#content {
    display: table;
}

#pageFooter {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

And the HTML code is:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="pageFooter">Page </div>
  multi-page content here...
</div>
```

The approach above works on FF but not on Chrome. It seems like `thead/tfoot` of chrome repeats on every printed page on print preview, but it doesn't results in any counter increment. The same counter value is printed on every printed page.

I also tried approaches that involve `@page`, but this seems to stop working a couple of years ago.

Example (copied from [Browser Support for CSS Page Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers)):

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
    @top-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

**Does anyone know a workaround for this problem? Or Am I dead in the water?** Any javasript/nodejs solution is welcome.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768941/how-to-print-with-page-numbers-in-media-print/43768942#43768942).

Comment: I think I should have mentioned it, that link use methods that involve hard coding page number. The content that I have to print is dynamic, so it's impossible to figure out where to place the page number beforehand.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html Seems very similar issue.

Comment: I answered  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html/58059786#58059786 its working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to add page numbers when printing under Chrome/Chromium, one easy solution is to use [Paged.js](https://www.pagedjs.org/).

This JS library takes your HTML/CSS and cuts it into pages, ready to print as a book, that you will preview in your browser. It makes the `@page` and most the CSS3 specifications work for Chrome.

### Solution if you are OK with cutting your view into pages, ready to print

Just add their CDN in the `head` tag of your page :

```
<link href="path/to/file/interface.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You can then add page numbers by using the automated counter `page`. Example :

HTML to put anywhere you want to display the current page number:

```
<div class="page-number"></div>
```

CSS to make the number appear in the div :

```
.page-number{
  content: counter(page)
}
```

The library also allows to easily manage page margins, footers, headers, etc.

### Solution if you want to show numbers (and page breaks) only when printing

In this case, you need to apply the Paged.js CDN only when printing the document.
One way I can think of would be to add a `print me` button that fires Javascript to :

1. add the CDN to the page
2. **and then** execute  `window.print();` to launch the printing prompt of the navigator

Comment: Not work anymore with nowadays modern browser

Comment: I did this last month on Chromium. It does work.