# How to calculate total of printed page when printing document and display it in html?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

```
@media print {
    body { margin: 0; }
    thead { counter-reset: pages; }
    .page-number:before { counter-increment: pages; content: " "; }
    .page-number:after { counter-increment: page; }
    .page-number:after { content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); }
}
```

I am trying to display total of page number for every printed page.

For current it will only show total pages for the first page.

E.g. got total page 3, it shows

```
Page 1 of 3 , Page 2 of , Page 3 of
```

I am trying most of the sample, but no luck. Is there anyway to achieve this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQNreQ

Comment: I see your question is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654071/print-page-count-with-total-number-of-pages-using-css. Let try with this.

Comment: @KhoiNgoNguyen This is not working, that's why i am doing it in another way.

Comment: So that other question I closed was a repost of this?

Comment: @BoltClock I edited that other question in an attempt to get it reopened, because I wanted to post an answer. Should I just post here?

Comment: @Danield: Given that more time and energy has been invested by multiple people in the other question I think we'll keep that one instead.