# Error displaying page number. Convert from HTML to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

It is my target:

[image]

My counter must be in block.
I can't use `@bottom-right`

I have:

[image]

I found this issues:

```css
@page {
        counter-increment: page
    }

.page-counter {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    height: 32px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.page-counter::after{
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-counter"></div>
```

Where is my mistake? 
Thank you in advance.

I tried :

```
@page {
   .page-counter{
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34654071/6191987

Comment: @Vishnuprasad no. My counter must be in block. I can't use `@bottom-right`

Comment: @Vishnuprasad and it's doesn't working for me